# updating information with Php-Mysqli

Tags: php, if-statement

i'm watching a tutorials about CMS with OOP - PHP & RainTPL

when i try something like http://localhost/cms/admin/updateuser.php?id=4

it has ID so if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0) will be executed

but ( else ) executed too because it update the user !!

```
    public function UpdateUser()
    {
       if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)
       {
           $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
           $user = $this->usersModel->GetById($id);
           System::Get('tpl')->assign($user);
           System::Get('tpl')->draw('updateuser');
       }
       else
       {
           if(isset($_POST['UpdateUser']))
           {
                //Variables
               $name       = $_POST['name'];
               $username   = $_POST['username'];
               $email      = $_POST['email'];
               $admin      = (int)$_POST['admin'];
               $id         = (int) $_POST['id'];

               //Validation


               //array Data

               $data = array(
                   'name'      => $name,
                   'username'  => $username,
                   'email'     => $email,
                   'is_admin'  => $admin
               );

               if($this->usersModel->Update($id,$data))
               {
                   System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','User Updated');
                   System::Get('tpl')->draw('success');
               }
               else
               {
                   System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Error Updating User');
                   System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');
               }


           }
           else
           {
               //No Id
               System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','NO USER CHOSEN');
               System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');
           }

       }
   }
```

[image: localhost/cms/admin/updateuser.php]

`if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)`

will be executed & else too how in same time !!!!

when i try something like this http://localhost/cms/admin/updateuser.php?id=4

if statement should be executed without else statement because it can  Get the id from the url

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)
```

i need someone explain how does it work ?

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: It's weird, to make sure you've got the situation right  try to add marks in if and else blocks, for example echo "if"; in if block and echo "else"; in else block. And if will see both "if" and "else" on your page let us know =)

Comment: if statement works here http://i.imgur.com/DYFC65O.png and else statement works here  http://i.imgur.com/kVp4sa7.png !?

Comment: it is impossible for both branches of an `if()` to be executed. if you ARE getting both branches executed, then most likely your script is running twice, each time taking one of the paths.

Comment: How I can see in your screenshots they  aren't executed simultaneously, but in different requests. The if-block is executed on an initial request, and the else-block on subsequent request, probably when you hit save button.

Comment: you mean something like updateuser.php?id=5 if will be executed then updateuser.php will be shown so it will call the function again and if will not work because there's no id in the url ! then it will update and draw the page (success)